# Erro ao enviar arquivo ZIP via Intent no Android

Tags: android, arquivo-zip, android-intent

Estou tentando enviar um arquivo ZIP via Intent no Android com o código abaixo:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(out));
sendIntent.setType("application/zip");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Porém apenas consigo enviar se for via whatsapp, outros apps como Gmail, Outlook, OneDrive ou Google Drive retornam erros do tipo "não foi possível anexar/enviar o arquivo".

Modifiquei a última linha do Intent para:

```
startActivityForResult(sendIntent, ZIP_OK);
```

Onde *ZIP_OK* = 101;

Em:

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)

O *resultCode* retorna como 0 (zero) se não for via whatsapp.

Alguém sabe o que faltou eu fazer, ou o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para compartilhar um arquivo é necessário passar uma **URI** com referência à localização dele, você pode experimentar:

```
Uri.fromFile(File file)
```

ou

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(Context context, String authority, File file)
```

Documentação:

- [fromFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#fromFile(java.io.File))
- [getUriForFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#geturiforfile)

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!!